# converting a VB coded UI test to C# in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have created a coded UI test using visual studio , I got the code in VB and I need it in c# ,is there a way to convert it to c# using visual studio? or that I must do the coded UI process all over again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem last year where I was asked to recode a project from VB to C#. I ended up re-recording the entire project in C# since the Designer Files are computer generated, they can't be editted by the UI Tools if they're VB then converted to C#. It also gave the opportunity to redesign the tests in a more functional way.

Comment: I did the same after all ,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VB test handy to check this, but you could try using a web based converter and go from there. Might be better than starting from scratch.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/